# setImageResource Crashing Program

Tags: java, android, image, resources

My program is crashing whenever I try to run the line:

```
d1.setImageResource(R.drawable.clubs9);
```

I cannot figure out why.  It seems identical to another program I have that works using a similar line of code.  I have tried adding getResources().getDrawable(), but then it will not compile.  I am completely stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

```
public class TCP extends Activity {
    private List<Card> cards;
    private ImageButton deal;
    private ImageButton fold;
    private ImageView d1;
    private ImageView d2;
    private ImageView d3;
    private ImageView p1;
    private ImageView p2;
    private ImageView p3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tcp);
        createDeck();
        d1.setImageResource(R.drawable.clubs9);
    }
```

---

XML

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/d1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/p1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/d2"
    android:src="@drawable/diamondsq" />
```

---

LOGCAT:

```
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     ... 11 more
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at com.evorlor.threecardpoker.TCP.deal(TCP.java:64)
08-04 12:11:49.154: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Did you assign the value to d1 in createDeck();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException because your d1 is null
```

so use

```
d1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.d1);
```

so your code should be

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tcp);
        createDeck();
        d1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.d1);
        d1.setImageResource(R.drawable.clubs9);
    }
```

Comment: Excellent thank you!  Any idea why I did not have to do that on another program? (Without getting into too much depth, if you know off the top of your head).

Comment: @Evorlor are you sure for that program ?

Comment: actually i had an extension on it and cant quite remember what that extension does, but that probably has something to do with it.  Thanks so much guys for reducing my ignorance!

Comment: @Evorlor  as your are declaring like `private ImageView d1;` and using it like `d1.setImageResource(R.drawable.clubs9);` just think about it whats the connection between your imageview in xml and imageview d1 withoud `d1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.d1);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem here.

If you are calling it from onCreate, make sure you are calling setImageResource AFTER setContentView.

onCreate:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.setContentView(R.layout.myAct);
myBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myBtn);
myBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.mypng);
```